# how to move to another web page by react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to move from page ("A") to page ("B") on button click, I mean I have a function which handles button click and inside that function I want to move to the PAGE B, I know about Link to approch but it is not suitable in that case,
I also hear about something called history inside React-router-dom but to tell the truth it seems to be very tough, btw i also wanna send some datas to that page

Comment: Please include the code you have written so far.

Answer (score 0):

Use this. "/dashboard" is the name of your route

```
this.props.history.push('/dashboard')
```

Documentation: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history

Answer (score 0):

if you use browserHistory you can use this code to go to another page(component) without refreshing the whole page like when you click on a normal link

```
    browserHistory.push('/your_route_spicified_in_router')
```